# Проблемы с карточками товара

Tags: html, css

У меня есть карточки товара, когда я их соединяю они идут по вертикали хотя мне нужно чтобы шли по горизонтали. Как это сделать?

```
<div class="product-wrap">
    <div class="product-item">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/VfLQata.png" alt="">
        <div class="product-buttons">
            <a href="#" class="button">В корзину</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="product-title">
        <a href="#">Тест 1</a>
        <span class="product-price">₽ 1999</span>
    </div>

    <div class="product-item">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/VfLQata.png" alt="">
        <div class="product-buttons">
            <a href="#" class="button">В корзину</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="product-title">
        <a href="#">Тест 2</a>
        <span class="product-price">₽ 1999</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.product-wrap {
    width: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: white;
    padding: 0 0 20px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.product-item {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.product-wrap img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
.product-buttons {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
    opacity: 0;
    transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}
.button {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #c0a97a;
    font-size: 12px;
    width: 140px;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    border: 2px solid #c0a97a;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0);
    transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}
.button:before {
    content: "\f07a";
    margin-right: 10px;
}
.product-item:hover .product-buttons {
    opacity: 1;
}
.product-item:hover .button {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
}
.button:hover {
    background: black;
}
.product-title {
    color: #5e5e5e;
}
.product-title a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #2e2e2e;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin: 15px 0 5px;
    padding-bottom: 7px;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}
.product-title a:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 40px;
    height: 2px;
    background: #2e2e2e;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -20px;
    bottom: 0;
    transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}
.product-title a:hover {
    color: #c0a97a;
}
.product-title:hover a:after {
    background: #c0a97a;
}
.product-price {
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #c0a97a;
    font-weight: 700;
}
```

Тестировал разные варианты - толку ноль. Спасибо заранее

Answer (score 0):

`.product-item` и `.product-title` обернуть еще в один `div`. Далее, этому диву применить, например `display: inline-block;`

Но я бы использовал flexbox. Также оборачиваете `.product-item` и `.product-title` обернуть еще в один div, а `.product-wrap` применяете `display: flex;`

```html
<div class="product-wrap">
    <div>
        <div class="product-item">
            ....
        </div>
        <div class="product-title">
            ....
        </div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <div class="product-item">
            ...
        </div>
        <div class="product-title">
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<style>
    .product-wrap {
        ...
        display: flex;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: А можете обвернуть? Я как только не обворачивал по первому способу, не получалось

Comment: Прикалываетесь чтоли?
... поправил свой ответ добавив html код